# Can I resize my BitLocker partition without losing data?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, filesystems, bitlocker

I have Windows installed on my work laptop which I do not have admin rights (BitLocker filesystem).

I want to shrink that partition so I can dual-boot Manjaro along side the Windows.

From Manjaro installation ISO I can resize that partition,
but my question is, **is there any guarantee that my windows partition won't lose data or go corrupted?**

Comment: Since you don't have Administrator rights then you will be unable to change the size of the partition.  You should ask that your IT Administrator perform this step for you.  The alternative is to disable BitLocker protection on the drive, extend the size of the partition using the appropriate tool outside of Windows, then enable BitLocker protection.  Of course, if I was your IT Administrator, and any user did this without my express permission, they would be fired immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing a Bitlocker partition is best done via the Disk Management tool.

There is an answer on our site at the post
[How can I resize a windows-bitlocker partition with gparted](https://superuser.com/questions/1458673/how-can-i-resize-a-windows-bitlocker-partition-with-gparted)
that explains how to do this via a Live Linux DVD.

However, this process is risky, in that the answerer once lost his disk while trying
it himself. To recover from such an error, if it arrives, you should take an
image backup of the entire hard disk and have a bootable DVD with which you can
restore the disk if the worst happens.

There are better solutions than dual-booting Linux, such as WSL, but they all require
administrative permissions to put in place.

Comment: Creating the backup of the drive, necessary to prevent issues when they arrive, likely will require elevated permissions.  I suppose you could create those backups outside of Windows, but then you are dealing with an image that you cannot test or deploy yourself, so is it really worth anything?

Comment: @Ramhound: There are several bootable products that can take an image backup. I agree, given the risk and the lack of admin permissions, that it might not be worth it.

Comment: That presumes that the author can change the boot order, which will of course be a configuration change, which means the BitLocker recovery must be provided.  Good luck explaining that...

Comment: It's funny that I'd need to shrink the partition so I could back it up at a reasonable size. So it's a chicken and an egg problem for me. To backup it up I need to shrink it, because for the backup software it's a large blob of random noise. But to make that safe I need to back up first...

Comment: 1) wsl sucks, don't use it. wsl kills linux distros. 

2)You can just disable HDD cryptography in Windows settings (just search for "bitlocker" and you will find it)... but before doing that, you have to backup your hdd bitlocker partition key (search on web, for example: howto-connect.com/get-bitlocker-recovery-key-cmd-windows-10). After that you can finally restart and boot from your linux live usb, and you will be able to access and resize windows partition, so you'll be able to install your linux distro.

Comment: 3) When your linux distro will be installed, if you want to bring cryptography in windows partition back, you will have to boot windows (NOT from linux grub bootloader, BUT selecting windows via bios boot options), and then enable hdd bitlocker cryptography back. Finally restart, and when you'll try to boot windows you will be asked to write the bitlocker key, so write the key that you backupd.